# JavaScript Custom Analytics (Not GA)

Tags: javascript, analytics

I need to make an embeddable tracking code for my apps users and I'm having trouble getting pointed in the right direction.

I know some sites at one point used a 1x1 image to track pageviews, is this still something apps do?

I'm planning on using something like MaxCDN to server my script and I understand how to write the embed code so that it's async.  Every time I try to Google for answers the results are flooded with scripts that are already written (Google Analytics).  Are there any tutorials out there or can anyone elaborate on the concept behind tracking pageview and clicks with JS.

Thanks in advance for the help/advice.

Comment: What's the reason for using your own solution instead of an existing one?

Comment: Good question.  The nature of my application is advertising based, so I need to provide individual analytics for each of my user's sites.

Comment: Ah... maybe you can still use http://piwik.org/.

Comment: That looks interesting, but I'm not using a LAMP stack on the backend.  I will take a look at the source and see how they are implementing things though.  Thanks for the link.